# Rebuilding arrays

Tags: php, wordpress, laravel, eloquent

I'm working on a tool that fetches stuff from the Wordpress database and handles it in different ways. One of the things I've done is build a simple array called `$category`, which contains the contents of `wp_terms where term_id = <what the user picked>`.

Unfortunately, it doesn't contain everything I want, so I've also populated `$category->taxonomy` with the relevant details from `wp_term_taxonomy where term_id = <what the user picked>`. It's a one-to-one relationship, so no problems there.

However, I've also got a bunch of stuff I need in `wp_termsmeta`, where there's a one-to-many relationship of multiple lines with the same `term_id`. So what I get is something like this:

```
{
  "term_id" : 9813,
  "name" : "Who's Who",
  "slug" : "ww",
  "term_group" : 0,
  "taxonomy" : 
  {
    "term_taxonomy_id" : 9832,
    "term_id" : 9813,
    "taxonomy" : "category",
    "description" : "Who's Who is the CSICON Network's very own show about Doctor Who!",
    "parent" : 0,
    "count" : 58
  },
  "meta" : [
    {
      "meta_id" : 8490,
      "terms_id" : 9813,
      "meta_key" : "hosts",
      "meta_value" : "1, 2"
    },
    {
      "meta_id" : 8492,
      "terms_id" : 9813,
      "meta_key" : "thumbnail",
      "meta_value" : "http://csicon.fm/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/ww_4-248x248.jpg"
    }
  ]
}
```

We've got `term_id`, `name`, `slug`, and `term_group` from `wp_terms` in `$category`, then a bunch of stuff in `$category->taxonomy` and then a bunch of things under `$category->meta`.

*And now for the problem*.

If I want to access, say, the thumbnail URL, I'm going to have to traverse down to `$category->meta[1]->meta_value`, but I can't always know that it'll be `[1]`. For other categories, it might be `[0]` or `[2]`. All I know for sure is that it's the `[n]` that has `meta_key = thumbnail`.

Ideally, I would want a good way to iterate through `meta` and simply save the values for each `meta_key` as a "real" key under `$category`, so `$category->thumbnail` would return the `meta_value` currently stored there ... But I'll settle with a reliable way of always finding the right `meta_value` for a specific `meta_key`.

Any thoughts? :)

**SOLVED**

Thanks! Instead of `$category['meta'] = Category::find($term_id)->catMeta;`, I'm now running the following code, and it does exactly what I wanted.

```
$metaTemp = Category::find($term_id)->catMeta;
$metaTable = json_decode(json_encode($metaTemp), FALSE);
foreach($metaTable as $key => $value) {
    $category[$value->meta_key] = $value->meta_value;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest converting meta from an array to an object where properties of that object would be meta_keys. So you get this structure:

```
{
  "term_id" : 9813,
  "meta" : {
    "hosts" : {
      "meta_id" : 8490,
      "terms_id" : 9813,
      "meta_key" : "hosts",
      "meta_value" : "1, 2"
    },
    "thumbnail" : {
      "meta_id" : 8492,
      "terms_id" : 9813,
      "meta_key" : "thumbnail",
      "meta_value" : "http://csicon.fm/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/ww_4-248x248.jpg"
    }
  }
}
```

So that way search for the right meta would have a constant cost in time rather than linear.

your clients would search for it like so: `$category->meta->hosts`

Comment: If there multiple entries can share a meta_key then you'd have arrays rather than objects as meta object properties.

Comment: This got me going in the right direction and I found a solution that worked! Original post edited.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks! Instead of `$category['meta'] = Category::find($term_id)->catMeta;`, I'm now running the following code, and it does exactly what I wanted.

```
$metaTemp = Category::find($term_id)->catMeta;
$metaTable = json_decode(json_encode($metaTemp), FALSE);
foreach($metaTable as $key => $value) {
    $category[$value->meta_key] = $value->meta_value;
}
```